# How to run android app for phone in smart watch?

Tags: android, wear-os, sony-smartwatch

I developed an application in android studio which is run on mobile device. Now i want to run the Same application in smart watch.

Is it possible?

If it is possible than What configuration do i need to change?

Please Help.

Comment: No this is not possible. You can add a module for Android Wear inside your project. You can find more information [here](https://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html)

Comment: if we create new android application and select both phone and smart watch option than is it possible to run the application in both devices

Comment: Yes it is possible then. Unless you have a module for android wear you cannot run your application for the wearable

Comment: You Have To Create Seprate Module In Studio For Smartwatch and apk is also differ than mobile

Comment: if i add a new module for smartwatch then it will create a 2 apk file?

Comment: Which Sony smartwatch do you have?

Comment: In any smart watch.

Comment: Is your smartwatch an Android wear based watch? There are a few smartwatches currently available that run on different platforms that are not compatible. Depending on how you wrote your code you may have to re-write some or all of it to make it work.

Comment: Yaa... My smart watch is android wear base